# Is Littlewood's law true?

Tags: probability-theory

Littlewood's law states that a person can expect to experience an event with odds of one in a million (defined by the law as a "miracle") at the rate of about one per month. This is attributed to the theory of truly large numbers.

I know that Littlewood's point of view is defendable. However, the question I want to ask is: Is this "law" regarded with seriousness in the mathematical community (read: is it a proven fact or is it just a hypothesis?), and is there scientific evidence of the phenomenon?

Comment: makes me think of this line from Terry Pratchett: “Scientists have calculated that the chances of something so patently absurd actually existing are millions to one.
But magicians have calculated that million-to-one chances crop up nine times out of ten.”

Comment: It depends on what is meant by "one in a million" (is this a rate over some time period)? Keep in mind that there are bazillions of rare events out there with similar probabilities. The chance that *at least one* happens in a month is considerably higher. In other words while coincidences are rare, they happen in many contexts, which greatly increase the chances of seeing one.

Answer (score 1):

It's not really a mathematical claim, so mathematics as such take no position of it.

Almost the entire content of the claim depends on what exactly one considers an "event" worth caring about in this context to be. If I throw a fair coin twenty times and note down the result, then with mathematical certainty the odds of me having got *that exact sequence* of heads and tails will be precisely $1:1,048,575$. According to the premises of the "law" then, apparently me deciding to throw a coin twenty times will guarantee that I'm going to experience a miracle!

Or even without throwing coins, if it's raining and I look at the window, the odds of having exactly *that* distribution of raindrops with respect to each other will be well below one to a million.

But of course me getting `THHHTTHHHTTTHHTHHHTT` by flipping coins isn't really a miracle. That's an entirely humdrum and non-distinguished series of throws. And that's the problem with interpreting the claim.

What we really need to ask if we want to find out if the law is true is: **What counts as an "event" here?** And that is not a mathematical question.

Littlewood's law is then really a claim about psychology or perception rather than about mathematics. It claims:

> Of all the trillions of possible happenings with one-to-a-million-chances, there are *so many* that would strike us as surprising if they actually happened and someone noticed, that a person will come across the *unfulfilled possibility* of one of them happening every few seconds on average.

(There are about 2.5 million seconds in a month).

But that is really a claim about what we're capable of being surprised by, not one of probability theory.